# PHP: how to populate an input SELECT field with values from mysql DB table

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, input

I have mysql table MYTABLE with columns (id, value)

I have a form with an input dropdown menu and I would like to populate this (input SELECT) field with the values from MYTABLE.

In a few, if I click the SELECT field, I should see the list of "VALUES". When selected a value, I should also take its own "ID" from MYTABLE...

How can I do?

thanks!

Comment: Loop over your result set, and inside the loop, output the proper HTML code for the `option` elements you need ...? What actual _problem_ are you having with this? Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP try this :

```html
<select class="form-control" id= "MYTABLE-dropdown" name="MYTABLE" required>     
<option value="">Select value</option>  
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $s) {?>   
<option value="<?=$s['id']?>"><?=$s['value']?></option>  
<?php } ?> 
</select>
```